# Running Blazor Hosted App from command line

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net-core, blazor

I have a Blazor hosted application with a client (webassembly), server and shared project (from the webassembly hosted template).  It runs fine from Visual Studio, but I don't know how to run it from the command line.  I've tried:

1. dotnet run (from the solution, root project and server project directories)
2. Running the exe built by Visual Studio from the netcoreapp3.1 directory under the server project
3. Running the dll (using the dotnet command) from the netcoreapp3.1 directory under the server project
4. Both 2 and 3 but from the publish directory

All of them fail.  Does anyone know how I would run this from the command line?  I want to push it to Cloud Foundry but cannot without knowing how to run it.

Comment: Item 2 works for me. Describe what you see. Just "All of them fail" isn't helpful.

Comment: And that helped solve my issue....  I was about to put the stack trace into my question and read it again and it suddenly hit me what was wrong.  Stupid dev vs release bug in my code.

Comment: @henk-holterman - I lied....  the server part is running when I run the server exe now, but it's not finding my pages.  Are you having that issue?  Did your page come up ok?  My main layout and nav menu come up, but the page says "Sorry, there's nothing at this address.".

Comment: From the standard template out it works fine. Did you add any Authorization related code?

Comment: I created a new Blazor client-side app with ASP.Net Core hosting, did a "dotnet build -c Release" and "dotnet publish -c Release" from the solution directory, went into the server\bin\release\netcoreapp3.1\publish directory, ran the EXE, opened a browser to http://localhost:5000 and got the same message as above ("Sorry, there's nothing at this address").

Comment: No repro - that works fine over here.

Comment: What can you learn from the Server console window?

Comment: I got it!  I see an error in the dev tools in the browser that it can't find Blazorapp.shared.pdb.  I tried setting up Blazor client debugging in my Edge Dev browser and it must be expecting PDB files now.  Opened the site in Chrome and it now works.  Thank you!

Comment: I just ran into this myself today, so I've added what hopefully is a definitive answer.

Comment: Can you edit your question to include any error messages that you receive when performing each of the actions that you have mentioned @BrianM?

Answer (score 2):

On .NET 5, I was able to get my Blazor Client-Side App to run by using `dotnet run`

```
cd C:\path\to\source\server
dotnet run
```

It should say something like `Now listening on https://localhost:5001`, and you should be able to navigate there in your browser.

If that doesn't work, you may need to configure your SSL cert. I had to add this `"Key"` section to my `appsettings.json`. Note, this applies to published and release builds - more info [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/identity-api-authorization?view=aspnetcore-5.0#example-deploy-to-a-non-azure-web-hosting-provider)

```
  "IdentityServer": {
    "Clients": {
      "BlazorApp.Client": {
        "Profile": "IdentityServerSPA"
      }
    },
    "Key": {
        "Type": "Store",
        "StoreName": "My",
        "StoreLocation": "CurrentUser",
        "Name": "CN=localhost"
      }
  },
```

You can view your certs by using `ls`

```
ls Cert:\CurrentUser\My\{thumbprint}
```

Just use tab completion to figure out the path

Answer (score 1):

A hosted Blazor app (that is, an app with a Blazor client part as well as a server Web API part) is created this way in the Windows command prompt:

```
md NameOfYourApp

cd NameOfYourApp

dotnet new blazorwasm --hosted
```

This creates a Blazor app with Client, Server, and Shared folders under NameOfYourApp.

Using `dotnet run` within the Client or Server folders won't work properly.  Instead, to run your app from the command line, run the Server .exe file created when you build:

```
dotnet build

cd Server\bin\Debug\net5.0

NameOfYourApp.Server.exe
```

(If you don't switch to the directory of the .exe, your app won't be able to find the appsettings.json file.)